# Bash: Why can't I assign an absolute path to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to assign an absolute path to a variable in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR= "/home/foobar"

echo "$DIR/test"
```

The output:

```
./test.sh: line 2: /home/foobar: Is a directory
/test
```

I don't understand what is happening there, please help me.

Comment: if MS-Windows was involved in creating your file, also do `dos2unix myscript`. (no spaces allowed around `=` is still true). Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space before `"/home/foobar"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/foobar"

echo "$DIR/test"
```

Comment: @user4133128 That's extremely surprising. I've just tried on my machine and for me it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try in another shell.

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR='/home/foobar'
echo "$DIR/test"
```

Or if you want to check if the variable is getting initialized or not using this.

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR='/home/foobar'
[ -z "$DIR" ] && echo "Variable not declared" && exit
echo "$DIR/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is

```
[ assignment=value ... ] command arguments
```

so you are doing an assignment of `DIR=` and running the command `/home/foobar` -- which of course isn't a valid command, but a directory; hence the error message.

Try this:

```
DIR=/home/foobar bash -c 'echo "DIR is \"$DIR\""'   # DIR is "/home/foobar"
echo "done. DIR is now \"$DIR\""   # DIR is now ""
```

and you will see that `DIR` is assigned only during the first command, then lost.

To set it for the remainder of your script, you can do

```
DIR=/home/foobar
echo "DIR is now $DIR"
```

and if you want to expose it to child processes, you can add an `export`:

```
DIR=/home/foobar
bash -c 'echo "Before export: DIR is \"$DIR\""'  # DIR is ""
export DIR
bash -c 'echo "After export: DIR is \"$DIR\""'   # DIR is "/home/foobar"
```